# Academic journals for publishing usability research?

Tags: usability, ux-field, research

In most scientific disciplines, research is published in academic journals, undergoing scrutiny based on quality criteria such as peer review, standardized presentation structure, etc. However, when it comes to usability, most research is presented on websites of professional nature, including magazines, portals, blogs, etc.

While some of these sources may be of high quality, their nature is not bound by academic and scientific rigor. Are you aware of any academic journals dedicated to web usability research?"

Answer (score 1):

There was the [Journal of Usability Studies](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/journal/journal-of-usability-studies) which changed its name to the more generic [Journal of User Experience](https://uxpajournal.org/journal-user-experience/). As they state on that second link, "Over the past two years, the percentage of papers we’ve published on the topic of usability studies has declined while papers more generally about UX have increased"

So just "web" usability research is probably too over-specific to sustain a journal by itself - so articles on web usability research are likely to turn up across a range of journals - Interactions, IJHCS, IJHCI etc - https://ergonomicsblog.uk/ux-journals/

Don't forget conferences like ACM SIGCHI either - in computing the top academic research conferences are peer-reviewed and often harder to get into than the journals!